# gulp-cache: How can I use a file cache for LESS builds

Tags: maven, gulp

We are using gulp to compile all our LESS files into the target/ of a Maven project. This task alone takes ~51secs, so we would like to speed it up and skip unchanged LESS files. We need a file cache because gulp is called from Maven and the build runs inside an IDE, so the gulp process cannot stay in memory.

At best, the cached CSS files should be copied to target/ even if /target was deleted by a Clean & Build.

Here's my code:

```
var cache = require('gulp-cache');
var fileCache = new cache.Cache({ cacheDirName: 'gulp-cache' });

gulp.task('less', function () {
    return gulp.src([webappPath + '/**/*.less'])
            .pipe(fileCache('less'))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(less({
                paths: [path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes')],
                plugins: [cleancss],
                relativeUrls: true
            }))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(target));
    ;
});
```

The line `.pipe(fileCache('less'))` runs into an error:

> TypeError: fileCache is not a function.

(Documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cache )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The `gulp-cache` plugin needs to wrap your `less` plugin. That way only files that have changed will be passed through to `less`.

(2) You don't necessarily need to instantiate your own `cache.Cache` object. `gulp-cache` will create one for you if you don't. You only need to do it yourself if you want to have multiple caches. In that case you can pass the `cache.Cache` object using the `fileCache` option.

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src([webappPath + '/**/*.less'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(cache(less({
      paths: [path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes')],
      plugins: [cleancss],
      relativeUrls: true
    }), {
      fileCache: new cache.Cache({ cacheDirName: 'gulp-cache' })
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(target));
});
```

Comment: Sven, thanks a lot - works like a charm. I am down to 14secs (probably due to the sourcemaps, I will experiment with that next).